# Error modulenotfounderror: no module named 'application' when deploying to AWS elastic beanstalk from AWS codebuild

Tags: python, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a python flask REST server to AWS using AWS codepipeline, codebuild and elastic beanstalk.

The error occurs on the deployment step.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'
[2023-07-10 13:52:15 +0000] [213333] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 213333)
[2023-07-10 13:52:15 +0000] [213329] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2023-07-10 13:52:15 +0000] [213329] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
[2023-07-10 13:52:16 +0000] [213335] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2023-07-10 13:52:16 +0000] [213335] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (213335)
[2023-07-10 13:52:16 +0000] [213335] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
[2023-07-10 13:52:16 +0000] [213339] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 213339
[2023-07-10 13:52:16 +0000] [213339] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
   worker.init_process()
 File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 92, in init_process
   super().init_process()
 File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
   self.load_wsgi()
 File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
   self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
   self.callable = self.load()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
   return self.load_wsgiapp()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
   return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
   mod = importlib.import_module(module)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1128, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1142, in _find_and_load_unlocked
```

In my application.py file I do define application:

```py
application = Flask(__name__)
```

In .ebextensions/python.config:

```py
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: application.py
```

My wsgi.py file:

```py
from application import application


def start():
    application.run(host='ipv4 address. should I be using something else?', port=5000)
```

First thing I tried was updating the buildspec file by adding:

```
- echo "Deploying to Elastic Beanstalk"
      - aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
      - aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --application-name ai-sam-dev --environment-name ai-sam-dev-env
```

created a gunicorn.conf.py file

```
import multiprocessing

bind = "0.0.0.0:8000"  # Bind the application to this address and port

# Number of worker processes to spawn
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1

# Module name of the Flask application
# Make sure this matches the name used in your `application.py` file
module_name = "application"

# Name of the callable within the Flask application
callable_name = "application"
```

Changed the application declaration:

```
application = app = Flask(__name__)
```

change wsgi.py path

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: myfolder/wsgi.py
```